# AES cipher block chaining in RPGLE

Tags: encryption, aes, ibm-midrange, rpgle, cbc-mode

I am looking for any clues as to how I can achieve cipher blocking chaining in RPGLE as I wish to encrypt data than is larger than 16 bytes.
My understanding is that this is a necessity for AES to ensure it is split into only 16 byte blocks.

I am using the Qc3EncryptData() API

```
  *******************************************************************
  *Data definitions
  *******************************************************************
  *ALGD0200 algorithm description structure
 DQC3D0200         DS
  *                                             Qc3 Format ALGD0200
 D QC3BCA                  1      4B 0
  *                                             Block Cipher Alg
 D QC3BL                   5      8B 0
  *                                             Block Length
 D QC3MODE                 9      9
  *                                             Mode
 D QC3PO                  10     10
  *                                             Pad Option
 D QC3PC                  11     11
  *                                             Pad Character
 D QC3ERVED               12     12
  *                                             Reserved
 D QC3MACL                13     16B 0
  *                                             MAC Length
 D QC3EKS                 17     20B 0
  *                                             Effective Key Size
 D QC3IV                  21     52
  *                                             Init Vector
  *ALGD0300 algorithm description structure
 DQC3D0300         DS
  *                                             Qc3 Format ALGD0300
 D QC3SCA                  1      4B 0
  *                                             Stream Cipher Alg
  *ALGD0400 algorithm description structure
 DQC3D0400         DS
  *                                             Qc3 Format ALGD0400
 D QC3PKA                  1      4B 0
  *                                             Public Key Alg
 D QC3PKABF                5      5
  *                                             PKA Block Format
 D QC3ERVED00              6      8
  *                                             Reserved
 D QC3SHA                  9     12B 0
  *                                             Signing Hash Alg
  *ALGD0500 algorithm description structure
 DQC3D0500         DS
  *                                             Qc3 Format ALGD0500
 D QC3HA                   1      4B 0
  *                                             Hash Alg
  *DATA0200 array data format structure
 DQC3A0200         DS
  *                                             Qc3 Format DATA0200
 D QC3DP                   1     16*
  *                                             Data Ptr
 D QC3DL                  17     20B 0
  *                                             Data Len
 D QC3ERVED01             21     32
  *                                             Reserved
  *KEYD0200 key description format structure
 DQC3D020000       DS
  *                                             Qc3 Format KEYD0200
 D QC3KT                   1      4B 0
  *                                             Key Type
 D QC3KSL                  5      8B 0
  *                                             Key String Len
 D QC3KF                   9      9
  *                                             Key Format
 D QC3ERVED02             10     12             inz(x'000000')
  *                                             Reserved
  *QC3KS                  13     13
  *
  *                                variable length
  *******************************************************************

  * API error structure
 D APIERR          DS
 D  ERRPRV                       10I 0 INZ(272)
 D  ERRLEN                       10I 0
 D  EXCPID                        7A
 D  RSRVD2                        1A
 D  EXCPDT                      256A
 D
  *Encrypt Data (OPM, QC3ENCDT; ILE, Qc3EncryptData) API protects
  *data privacy by scrambling clear data into an unintelligible form.
  *Qc3EncryptData  Pr                  ExtProc('Qc3EncryptData')
 D Qc3EncryptData  Pr                  ExtPgm('QC3ENCDT')
 D clrDta                       100a
 D clrDtaLen                     10I 0
 D clrDtaFmt                      8
 D algorithm                           like(QC3D0200)
 D algorithmFmt                   8
 D key                                 like(KeyC)
 D keyFmt                         8
 D srvProvider                    1
 D deviceName                    10
 D encryptedData                100a
 D encryptedBufL                 10I 0
 D encryptedRtnL                 10I 0
 D errcde                              like(APIERR)

  * Decrypt Data (OPM, QC3DECDT; ILE, Qc3DecryptData) API restores
  * encrypted data to a clear (intelligible) form.
  *Qc3DecryptData  Pr                  ExtProc('Qc3DecryptData')
 D Qc3DecryptData  Pr                  ExtPgm('QC3DECDT')
 D encryptedData                100a
 D encryptedDtaL                 10I 0
 D algorithm                           like(QC3D0200)
 D algorithmFmt                   8
 D key                                 like(keyC)
 D keyFmt                         8
 D srvProvider                    1
 D deviceName                    10
 D clrDta                       100a
 D clrDtaBufL                    10I 0
 D clrDtaRtnL                    10I 0
 D errcde                              like(APIERR)

 DQc3GenPRNs       Pr                  ExtPRoc('Qc3GenPRNs')
 D PrnDta                       512
 D PrnDtaLen                     10I 0
 D PrnType                        1
 D PrnParity                      1
 D errcde                              like(APIERR)

 D PrnDta          S            512
 D PrnDtaLen       S             10I 0
 D PrnType         S              1    inz('1')
 D PrnParity       S              1    inz('1')

 D clrDta          S            100a
 D clrDtaLen       S             10I 0
 D clrDtaFmt       S              8    inz('DATA0100')
 D algorithm       S                   like(QC3D0200)
 D algorithmFmt    S              8    inz('ALGD0200')
 D key             S                   like(KeyC)
 D keyFmt          S              8    inz('KEYD0200')
 D srvProvider     S              1    inz('1')
 D deviceName      S             10    inz(*blanks)
 D encryptedData   S            100a
 D encryptedDtaL   S             10I 0
 D encryptedBufL   S             10I 0
 D encryptedRtnL   S             10I 0
 D clrDtaBufL      S             10I 0
 D clrDtaRtnL      S             10I 0

 D KeyString       S            256
 D KeyC            S            256

 C* Block cipher algorithm
  * 20 DES
  * 21 Triple DES
  * 22 AES
 C                   Eval      QC3BCA = 22
  *Block length
  *  8  DES
  *  8  Triple DES
  * 16  AES
 C                   Eval      QC3BL  = 16
  *Mode
  * 0 ECB
  * 1 CBC
  * 2 OFB. Not valid with AES.
  * 3 CFB 1-bit. Not valid with AES.
  * 4 CFB 8-bit. Not valid with AES.
  * 5 CFB 64-bit. Not valid with AES
 C                   Eval      QC3MODE = '1'
  * Pad Option
  * 0 No padding is performed.
  * 1 Use the character specified in the pad character field for padding
  * 2 The pad counter is used as the pad character.
 C                   Eval      QC3PO   = '1'

  * Pad Character
 C                   Eval      QC3PC   = X'00'
  * Reserved
 C                   Eval      QC3ERVED = X'00'
  * MAC Length
  * This field is not used on an encrypt operation and must be set to
  * null(binary 0s).
 C                   Eval      QC3MACL  = X'00000000'
  * Effective key size
  * This field must be set to 0.
 C                   Eval      QC3EKS   = 0
  * Initialization vector
  * The initialization vector (IV). An IV is not used for mode ECB,
  * and must be set to NULL (binary 0s).
 C                   Eval      QC3IV = *AllX'00'
 C***                Reset                   encryptedData
 C****               Eval      encryptedBufL = %len(encryptedData)

 C*                  Eval      algorithm = %addr(QC3D0200)
 C                   Eval      algorithm = QC3D0200
  * Key Type            KeyFormat  KeyLength
  * 20 DES                     0          8(7 bits used,rightmost setbit
  * 21 Triple DES              0    8,16,24(7 bits used,rightmost setbit
  * 22 AES                     0   16,24,32
  * 30 RC4-compatible          0    1<->256
  * 50 RSA public              1
  * 51 RSA private             1
 C                   Eval      QC3KT = 22

  * Key Format
 C                   Eval      QC3KF = '0'
  * Key String
 C                   Eval      KeyString = pKeyString
  * Key Length
 C                   Eval      QC3KSL = %len(%trim(KeyString))
 C                   Eval      KeyC = QC3D020000 + %trim(KeyString)
 C                   Eval      Key  = KeyC


  * Encrypt
 C                   Select
 C                   When      pAction = 'E'
 C                   Eval      clrDta = pClrDta
 C                   Eval      clrDtaLen = %len(%trim(clrDta))
 C                   Eval      EncryptedData = *blanks
 C                   Eval      encryptedBufL = %size(encryptedData)
 C                   callP     Qc3EncryptData(
 C                                clrDta        :
 C                                clrDtaLen     :
 C                                clrDtaFmt     :
 C                                algorithm     :
 C                                algorithmFmt  :
 C                                key           :
 C                                keyFmt        :
 C                                srvProvider   :
 C                                deviceName    :
 C                                encryptedData :
 C                                encryptedBufL :
 C                                encryptedRtnL :
 C                                APIERR
 C                             )
 C                   ExSr      ChkErrCde
 C                   Eval      pEncDta = EncryptedData
  * Decrypt
 C                   When      pAction = 'D'
 C****               Eval      EncryptedData = %Trim(pEncDta)
 C                   Eval      EncryptedData = pEncDta
 C                   Eval      EncryptedDtaL = %len(%trim(EncryptedData))
 c                   If        EncryptedDtaL <> 16
 C                   Eval      EncryptedDtaL = 32
 C                   Endif
 C                   Eval      clrDta = *blanks
 C                   Eval      clrDtaBufL = %size(clrDta)
 C                   callP     Qc3DecryptData(
 C                                encryptedData :
 C                                encryptedDtaL :
 C                                algorithm     :
 C                                algorithmFmt  :
 C                                key           :
 C                                keyFmt        :
 C                                srvProvider   :
 C                                deviceName    :
 C                                clrDta        :
 C                                clrDtaBufL    :
 C                                clrDtaRtnL    :
 C                                APIERR
 C                             )
 C                   ExSr      ChkErrCde
 C                   Eval      pclrDta = ClrDta

 C                   Other
 C                   Eval      *InLr = *On
 C                   Endsl

 C                   Return
  **********************************************************************
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you trying to use the Qc3EncryptData() API?

Comment: Sorry ...yes I am, I've added some of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prototypes aren't the best...

Assuming a recent version of IBM i, you can have a char field of 16M, this is how you'd code a prototype that could handle encrypting up to 16MB of data

```
 D Qc3EncryptData  Pr                  ExtPgm('QC3ENCDT')
 D clrDta                          a   len(16733104) options(*varsize) const
 D clrDtaLen                     10I 0
```

In your **QC3D0200** algorithm description structure, you tell the API whether or not to pad (**QC3PO**) and what character to pad with (**QC3PC**).

With the above prototype and the proper settings, you can encrypt data upto 16MB.  If you pass for instance 100 bytes, the algorithm will automatically pad to 112 bytes...

You'd need to make sure that you allow for the automatic padding in your encrypted value buffer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this and provide an update shortly